# Perl comparison operator output

Tags: perl

I am not exactly sure what the output of a comparison is. For instance, consider

```
$rr = 1>2;
$qq = 2>1;

print $rr; #nothing printed
print $qq; #1 printed
```

Is `$rr` the empty string? Is this behavior documented somewhere? Or how can one tell for sure?

I was looking for the answer in Learning Perl by Schwartz et al., but could not immediately resolve the answer.

Comment: The result/value of a comparison like your examples is boolean, usually you use it directly in e.g. an `if(...)` to control program flow. You can also store the result in a scalar variable, like you did, and then do  `if($rr)`. Printing booleans is most readable done as `if($rr) {print "True"} else {print "False"}`. Please provide more context on what you otherwise want to achieve.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for your comment. However, it doesn't really answer my question as to what the scalar variable holds. As you know, there is no "boolean" type in Perl. It is well-known many numbers and strings evaluate to false, but does one know what exactly is stored in $rr? Is it implementation-dependent?

Comment: I know that there is no boolean type in Perl and did not intend to say so. Admittedly, my "Printing booleans..." could be read like that, but if was meant as short for "visualising such boolean results...". The "output of a comparison" is still boolean, i.e. part of boolean logic. The fact that they are stored as described in the good answer is what I learned here. I comented instead of answering because I was clear, that I coudl not aswer the specific "how is it stored" question. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators:

> Perl operators that return true or false generally return values that can be safely used as numbers. For example, the relational operators in this section and the equality operators in the next one return 1 for true and a special version of the defined empty string, "" , which counts as a zero but is exempt from warnings about improper numeric conversions, just as "0 but true" is.

So it what is returned is something that is an empty string in string context, and 0 in numeric context.

Comment: Hmm...it seems to always be the empty string, even in the numeric context, no? Unless I misunderstood what you mean by numeric context, in my example, everything is numeric, yet it still returned the empty string (nothing was printed).

Comment: @bilodeau1 In your code the only thing you do with `$rr` is to pass it to `print`, which uses it as a string. No numeric context here.

Comment: melpomene, thanks. Reading the perldoc more carefully, I now understand what ysth meant. What is returned neither truly an empty string or 0, but a special "dual" character that acts like an empty string or the 0, depending on what's "appropriate". I verified that $rr+1 does not issue a warning.

Comment: @bilodeau1, Compare `perl -we'my $x = "" + 0;'` and `perl -we'my $x = (1<0) + 0;'` and you'll see it's not just an empty string.